# switch statemen t javascript

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I made this code but it does not work at all
I am supposed to use the switch statement
Could you tell me please where is the error 
thanks a loot :)

```
var side == parseInt(prompt('Enter a number of side between 3 and 10: '));
var shape ==['triangle','square','pentagon','hexagon','heptagon','octagon','nonagon','octagon'];
switch (shape){
case== 3:
shape=[0];
break;
case== 4:
shape==[1];
break;
case== 5:
shape==[2];
break;
case== 6:
shape==[3];
break;
case== 7:
shape==[4];
break;
case== 8:
shape==[5];
break;
case== 9:
shape==[6];
break;
case== 10:
shape==[7];
break;
}
alert('The shape is' + shape);
```

Comment: You might want to look at [examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch#Examples) from some reputable documentation. Your syntax is completely wrong.

Comment: Learn how to use javascript. Here is a nice interactive [tutorial](https://www.codeschool.com/courses/javascript-road-trip-part-1).

Comment: Also for your specific program you could avoid the switch and do: `alert(shape[side-3] || "something")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `==` when you should use `=`. In your switch you want to check on user input (`side`) and then case just need options no symbols. Finally shape needs to reassigned to the value from the array.

```js
var side = parseInt(prompt('Enter a number of side between 3 and 10: '));
var shape =['triangle','square','pentagon','hexagon','heptagon','octagon','nonagon','octagon'];
switch (side){
case 3:
shape=shape[0];
break;
case 4:
shape=shape[1];
break;
case 5:
shape=shape[2];
break;
case 6:
shape=shape[3];
break;
case 7:
shape=shape[4];
break;
case 8:
shape=shape[5];
break;
case 9:
shape=shape[6];
break;
case 10:
shape=shape[7];
break;
}
alert('The shape is ' + shape);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are making an array `shape=[0];` not referencing your array that has the values.

Comment: I think there might be a slight syntax problem with the `case` clauses too :)

Comment: sorry I am a total beginner can you explain me what should i do to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

You have syntax errors galore:

```
case== 3:
```

should be just

```
case 3:
```

and

```
shape==[1];
```

`==` tests for quality, so you're basically saying `shape is the same as an array containing the number 1`.

Comment: var grade = 80; var award; switch(grade) {
 case >= 70:
    award=’Distinction’;
    break;  
 case >= 60:
    award=’Merit’;
    break;
 case >= 40:
    award=’Pass’;
    break;
 case >= 40:
    award=’Fail’;
    break;
}    I am using this template as reference, this is the only course I have a bout the switch

Comment: You should have had this as your question because the answer to this isn't a switch statement either.

Comment: the reference is also totally wrong. `case` cannot be an expression. it has to be a VALUE. `case 70` works, `case >= 70` does not, and never will.

Answer (score 0):

Stop using `==` in place of `=`.

`==` is a comparison check, `=` is an assignment operator.

using switch:

```
var side = parseInt(prompt('Enter a number of side between 3 and 10')),
shapes = ['triangle','square','pentagon','hexagon','heptagon','octagon','nonagon','octagon'],
shape;
switch (side){
case 3:
    shape = shapes[0];
    break;
case 4:
    shape = shapes[1];
    break;
case 5:
    shape = shapes[2];
    break;
case 6:
    shape = shapes[3];
    break;
case 7:
    shape = shapes[4];
    break;
case 8:
    shape = shapes[5];
    break;
case 9:
    shape = shapes[6];
    break;
case 10:
    shape = shapes[7];
    break;
}
alert('The shape is ' + shape);
```

better way:

```
var side = parseInt(prompt('Enter a number of side between 3 and 10')),
shapes =    ['triangle','square','pentagon','hexagon','heptagon','octagon','nonagon','octagon'];

alert('The shape is' + shapes[side - 3]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a switch statement - you can have much shorter more concise code. You can just assign the shape, but make sure you check the prompted side is within range.

```
var shape = ['triangle','square','pentagon','hexagon','heptagon','octagon','nonagon','decagon'];

var side = parseInt(prompt('Enter a number of side between 3 and 10: '));

var userShape = shape[side - 3];

if (side < 3 || side > 10) {
    alert('Not a recognised shape')
} else {
    alert(userShape);
}
```

Unless you're sure you're not going to use the `shape` array again it's better to assign the result of checking the array to a new variable (here `userShape`) otherwise you're just overwriting the array.

Also, a ten-sided shape is a decagon :)

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/x3zpnnty/3)